# $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$ be a topology for $X$. $\mathcal{B}$ is a family such that for every $U\in \tau$, one is able to write $U=\cup_{i\in I}B_i$, as an arbitrary union of elements in $ \mathcal{B}$. I want to prove that if we take two elements $ B_1 , B_2\in \mathcal{B}$, if $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, there exists a $B_3$ such that $x\in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

My thoughts so far are that if $A^o$ denotes the interior of $A$ we have $B_1^o\cap B_2^o=(B_1\cap B_2)^o$  being open (by a well know result). Therefore $x\in B_1^o\cap B_2^o=\cup_{i\in I}B_i $ implies the existence of a $B_3$ such that $x\in B_3 \subset B_1^o\cap B_2^o =(B_1\cap B_2)^o \subset B_1\cap B_2$. However, it could be that we have a $x\in \partial (B_1\cap B_2)$ and this makes things considerably harder.

Comment: Do you require that $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\tau$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $B$ is a family of *open* sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true (unless $\mathcal B $ is contained in $\tau$, in which case it is easy to prove. For a counter-example let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal B$ be the collection of intervals $[a,b]$ with $-\infty < a <b <\infty$. Take $B_1=[0,1], B_2=[1,2]$ and $x =1$.